# Add some text to a QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtoolbar

I am having trouble adding some text in a QToolBar. I can only add Actions. Also I have two actions with their rerspectives icons in my QToolBar but I want to separate them and I can´t either.

My newbie approach was to add empty actions to simulate blank spaces between the icons. But the user can click on the blank spaces.

I am using the Design function of QT Creator. Some help would be really apreciated.

Comment: And where is the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't do it from within Designer:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1267

That's an oooold suggestion, too, with a low priority to boot, so it probably won't get fixed any time soon.

You can get your hands dirty and do it in [code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget), however.

Comment: I have very little time to finish this work. But it seems it is the only way. I will try to use code.

Comment: It won't take long! :)